# Connecting Oracle Linux database to AcGIS 10 on windows PC

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, linux, oracle-spatial

I am wondering if anyone has tried to connect from ArcGIS 10, to an oracle database stored on a Linux server?
I have no problems connecting to oracle from Arc when the data is stored on a windows box, but no matter the different combinations of host name / server name I insert to try and connect to the database which is stored on a Linux box I get an error.

Even if its a case of this is not possible, it would be nice to know so I can try and proceed down a different route.

Comment: Yes, it's possible to connect *from* ArcGIS *to* a supported 64-bit Oracle release (your title has the order flipped) on a supported Linux plattorm. You'll need to provide the exact service pack  applied to ArcGIS, the exact Linux release, the exact Oracle release, and the exact error.

Comment: You should also mention whether you applied the Oct 2014 CPU to Oracle that disabled the package used by Esri during connection, which is warned about as an issue at support.esri.com

Answer (score 1):

Connecting to a linux database is **absolutely** no different from connecting to a database on Windows, or any other platform for that matter. The interconnect protocol (SQL*net) is the same everywhere. The platforms for the client and server play no role here, neither does the fact that one is 32-bit and the other is 64-bit. Also the versions of the Oracle client and the Oracle server play little role: the protocol exchange is such that it will automatically adapt to the versions at both ends. So interconnection works with all reasonably recent versions of Oracle (say 10gR2, 11gR2, 12cR1) but they should also work with older versions (9i, even 8i). I have seen some incompatibilities reported between a 12c client and an 8.0 server ... but such is life.

What probably happens is that your Windows database runs on the same server as your ArcGIS 10 server whereas your Linux database runs on a different server. In one case you use possibly a direct connection (no IP) or maybe a local connection (localhost), whereas the connection to the Linux database is obviously remote and needs the full connection details: server name or IP address, TNS listener port, database service name or SID (and of course the proper credentials).

For a start it would really help if you tell us the exact error you are getting and the connection details you specify (server, port, service names). Connecting to an Oracle Database can fail for a variety of reasons, but they always have to do with some mis-configuration, either client or server side.

Debugging those issues can be very difficult when using client tools (like ArcGIS) that sometimes obfuscate the error messages they receive into some generic "connection failure" message, leaving you guessing and poking.

Debugging is best done in steps, using simple tools:

1) Confirm that the server is reachable:

```
ping <database_server>
```

2) Confirm that the TNS listener is reachable on the port you expect, and knows about your database:

```
tnsping <database_server>:<port>/<database_service>
```

for example:

```
tnsping db_server.acme.com:1521/orcl121.local
```

3) Confirm that the database is up and running and connected to your listener, and also that you are using the proper credentials.

```
sqlplus <username>/<password>@<database_server>:<port>/<database_service>
```

If you are not familiar with those techniques, I recommend you seek assistance from your database administrator.

BTW, what version of Oracle are we talking about ? On Windows ? On Linux ?

Comment: No, ArcGIS does not support all versions of Oracle between 8i and 12c -- Each release has a limited set of supported server versions. Application word size *does* make a difference, as Esri has only supported 64-bit servers since ArcGIS 10, and Desktop clients require 32-bit Oracle libraries. You should also mention that the Linux `iptables` firewall must be configured to allow connection through SQL*Net port 1521 (or whichever non-default port was chosen).

Comment: I agree that there are probably all kinds of dependencies between an application (like ArcGIS) and database version and word size. But Dean (the OP) only talks about problem connecting to a database. You are right that the error Dean gets could be some application-specific error. Still he should first make sure the base database connectivity works. Good point about the iptables firewall. I assumed (maybe incorrectly) that this Linux database is already used by a number of other applications from a variety of servers (so the proper port would be open).